# Why does the deployment process return below error?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, heroku

I am deploying python application on  `heroku`, connection string in **setting.py** is as per following:

```
import dj_database_url   ####not working for my case
        DATABASES = {
            'default': dj_database_url.config(
                default=os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL')
            )
        }
```

The dependencies in the **requirement.txt** have been deployed successfully.
Following is the error I got after deployment attempt ,any help would be welcome.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: relation "django_content_type" does not exist
LINE 1: ..."."app_label", "django_content_type"."model" FROM "django_co...
                                                             ^
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 365, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 332, in execute
    self.check()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 364, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 58, in _run_checks
    issues.extend(super()._run_checks(**kwargs))
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 351, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 73, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 40, in check_url_namespaces_unique
    all_namespaces = _load_all_namespaces(resolver)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 57, in _load_all_namespaces
    url_patterns = getattr(resolver, 'url_patterns', [])
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 36, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 536, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 36, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 529, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/app/restful01/urls.py", line 19, in <module>
    from .api import router
  File "/app/restful01/api.py", line 2, in <module>
    from toys import api_views as toys_views
  File "/app/toys/api_views.py", line 6, in <module>
    class allroom(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
  File "/app/toys/api_views.py", line 7, in allroom
    queryset = models.Toy.objects.all()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 155, in all
    return self.get_queryset()
  File "/app/.heroku/src/django-moderation/moderation/managers.py", line 129, in get_queryset
    return self.filter_moderated_objects(query_set)
  File "/app/.heroku/src/django-moderation/moderation/managers.py", line 42, in filter_moderated_objects
    if annotated_queryset.exists():
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 715, in exists
    return self.query.has_results(using=self.db)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 509, in has_results
    return compiler.has_results()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1032, in has_results
    return bool(self.execute_sql(SINGLE))
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1050, in execute_sql
    sql, params = self.as_sql()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 457, in as_sql
    from_, f_params = self.get_from_clause()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 719, in get_from_clause
    clause_sql, clause_params = self.compile(from_clause)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 390, in compile
    sql, params = node.as_sql(self, self.connection)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/datastructures.py", line 84, in as_sql
    compiler.query.where_class, self.table_alias, self.parent_alias)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/reverse_related.py", line 137, in get_extra_restriction
    return self.field.get_extra_restriction(where_class, related_alias, alias)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/contenttypes/fields.py", line 462, in get_extra_restriction
    contenttype_pk = self.get_content_type().pk
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/contenttypes/fields.py", line 458, in get_content_type
    for_concrete_model=self.for_concrete_model)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/contenttypes/models.py", line 51, in get_for_model
    ct = self.get(app_label=opts.app_label, model=opts.model_name)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 397, in get
    num = len(clone)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 254, in __len__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1179, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 54, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1063, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 100, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 68, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "django_content_type" does not exist
LINE 1: ..."."app_label", "django_content_type"."model" FROM "django_co...
```

Comment: Looks like the migrations were not created or applied.

Comment: In my procfile though on git  ,I have the setting for the migration to be perfomed,see following :release: python manage.py migrate
web: gunicorn restful01.wsgi --log-file -

Comment: You should show the definition for the Toy model. You seem to be using a third-party library (django-moderation) which is triggering a query at import time, which is causing your problem.

Comment: Hi Daniel,yes,I am using the django-moderation where I register my Toy model .moderation.register(Toy) ,what's the recommendation here ?

Comment: thanks Daniel, I have removed the django_moderation under installed app and comment the registered Toy model in moderator.py ,now migration to Heroku has been done successfuly,any idea what could be wrong with moderation ? I have the following in my requirements.txt.  -e git+git://github.com/dominno/django-moderation.git@565481f1832114da2d0c48b0c23977d4d3a9b914#egg=django_moderation.Note it's work fine locally

Answer (score 0):

Found this online.
You need to have virtualenv and pip installed. While working in your virtualenv (with it activated), you need to do a

```
pip install dj-database-url
```

Then you need to do:

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

Might be worth giving a shot.

Comment: I have virtual have created  locally and requirements file generated ,but I didnt create such on heroku

Answer (score 0):

It's actually a problem with django-moderation. You probably have a custom form somewhere where you reference a foreignKey to a moderated model. This will trigger a database lookup in the django-moderation code and it will fail when django doesnt have the required tables (before ./manage.py migrate is run).

Our current "best effort" solution approach:

```
class SomeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = SomeModel
        fields = [
            'problematic_field_reference_to_foreign_model_that_is_moderated',
            'some_other_field',
            'another_field',
        ]
        if ('makemigrations' in sys.argv or 'migrate' in sys.argv):
            fields.remove("problematic_field_reference_to_foreign_model_that_is_moderated")
```

Of course I am not proud of this but I need to move on.